# Obtener datos de una tabla dínamica en php usando javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código, debo traerme los datos de la fila actual usando javascript o jquery, intenté con ambos pero no funcionan bien, no traen el dato o lo traen en blanco. La idea es poner los datos en un modal poco despúes, pero no logró pasar de la prueba de obtener los datos

Este es el código que se trae los datos:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['id_user'])) {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'> top.document.location = '../login.php'; </script>";
  
}else{
require("../../php/connection.php");
$conn = DBManager::con();

$query ="SELECT * FROM `servicios`, `estado_varios`, `categoria_servicio`
WHERE servicios.estado = estado_varios.id_estado 
AND servicios.id_categoria = categoria_servicio.id_categoria_serv";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC); //Agarra los datos de la fila
?>
```

Aquí se genera la tabla en sí

```
<table class="table table-striped table-class" id="table-id" name="servicios_tabla">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nombre del servicio</th>
        <th>Categoria del servicio</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Acción</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
        echo "<tr><td id='id_servicio'>". $row['id_servicio'] ."</td><td id='nombre_servicio' class='nr'>" . $row['nombre_servicio'] . "</td><td>" . $row['categoria'] . "</td><td>" . $row['nombre_estado'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td><button onclick='llamar_datos()' class='btn btn-primary' id='modificar' name='modificar' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#GSCCModal'>Modificar</button></td></tr>";
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

La idea es que al presionar el boton llamado modificar, este llame a un código javascript que se agarra los datos de la fila en donde este

Esto es lo que intenté

```
function llamar_datos(){
  var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('#nombre_servicio').text();
  alert(id);
}
```

Así es como luce la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando declaras que `onclick` gatilla un cierto handler, a menos que le pases un argumento éste no tiene cómo saber a cuál fila te refieres. Mira por ejemplo la diferencia entre invocar al handler pasándole el elemento mismo vs nada.

```js
function ejecutar_sin_argumento() {
  alert(this.id)
}

function ejecutar_con_argumento(element) {
  alert(element.id)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="ejecutar_sin_argumento()" id="el_boton">Pínchame y te dijo mi Id</button>

<button onclick="ejecutar_con_argumento(this)" id="el_boton2">Yo sí te digo mi Id</button>
```

Lo que una función entiende por  `this` es abstracto en este punto. Cuando usas el clásico

```
jQuery('#elemento').on('click',function() {
   // como function tiene scope propio, 
   // `this`  es el elemento
})
```

El scope es distinto a cuando usas

```
jQuery('#elemento').on('click',() => {
   // no tiene scope propio, así que 
   // `this`  apunta al scope superior
})
```

En tu caso, no tiene caso esperar que el scope se transfiera mágicamente.

### Y cómo hace jQuery para adivinar el `this`?

Pensemos en un listener declarado como

```
   jQuery(...).on('click', function() { 
          alert(this.id); 
   });
```

La función ahí parece no tener parámetros, pero en javascript (así como en PHP y otros lenguajes) nada impide llamarla con argumentos extra y *cuando son funciones clásicas (no arrow)* puedes acceder a los argumentos  recibidos, en el objeto `arguments`.

jQuery se vale de eso para identificar qué evento invocó el handler, y si sabe el evento entonces también sabe el elemento, pues viene en la propiedad `target` del evento. Es como si hiciera:

const EventHandler = function() {
let evento = arguments[0];
alert(evento.target.id);
}

Veamos la comparación entre el handler con "función clásica" que adivina cosas misteriosamente, vs un intento de hacer lo mismo en una arrow function, vs la manera correcta para no perder de vista qué es lo que viaja de un handler a otro...

```js
$('#el_boton_A').on('click', function() {
  alert('Puedo inferir el ID porque tengo scope propio. ID=' + this.id);
});
$('#el_boton_B').on('click', () => {
  alert(window === this ? 'No tengo scope. `this` es igual a `window`' : this.id);
});
$('#el_boton_C').on('click', (event) => {

  alert('no tengo scope pero recibí el evento. ID= ' + event.target.id);
});
```

```css
button {
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #369;
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button style="color:#036" id="el_boton_A">`function()`  clásica, infiere el ID</button>

<button style="color:#900" id="el_boton_B">Arrow, no tiene scope propio ni `this` </button>

<button style="color:#373" id="el_boton_C">Esta arrow recibe el evento explícito</button>
```

### Entonces, volviendo a tu tabla dinámica

si vas a usar `onclick`, preocúpate de pasarle algún argumento. Si vas a declarar un listener sobre las filas, utiliza el argumento que te llegará aunque no lo hayas pedido. Ese argumento contiene al target que recibió el click.

```js
function llamar_datos1() {
  var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('#nombre_servicio').text();
  alert(id);
}
document.querySelector('#modificar2').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  alert('event.target.id: ' + event.target.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-striped table-class" id="table-id" name="servicios_tabla">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nombre del servicio</th>
      <th>Categoria del servicio</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Acción</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id='id_servicio'>1</td>
      <td id='nombre_servicio' class='nr'>Un servicio</td>
      <td>Plomería</td>
      <td>Pendiente</td> 
      <td><button onclick='llamar_datos1()' class='btn btn-primary' id='modificar' name='modificar' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#GSCCModal'>Modificar</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='id_servicio'>2</td>
      <td id='nombre_servicio' class='nr'>Otro servicio</td>
      <td>Carpintería</td>
      <td>Aprobado</td>
      <td><button class='btn btn-primary' id='modificar2' name='modificar' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#GSCCModal'>Modificar</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Cuando hayas resuelto esta parte, te vas a encontrar tarde o temprano con un problema ocasionado porque todas tus filas tienen el mismo ID en la primera y segunda columnas. Eso puede pasar desapercibido en tanto uses una búsqueda relativa como `closest()` pero no es correcto.

Answer (score 0):

En tu código se observan malas prácticas como son:

1. Asignar el mismo ID a varios elementos en el HTML que se produce en esta parte `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){` En el código de ejemplo **no he asignado ninguno de esos IDs repetitivos porque no se necesitan, no al menos para el propósito de la pregunta**. Si necesitas IDs por algún motivo asígnalos, pero garantizando que sean únicos. Y si no los necesitas, no los asignes, ¿para qué recargar el contenido innecesariamente?
2. Usar funciones in-line, que viola el principio de *[Separación entre estructura y comportamiento](https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_structure_and_behaviour)*

Dicho eso, y tratándose de una tabla, la cual se supone **siempre va a tener la misma cantidad de celdas en este contexto**, puedes fácilmente recoger los valores de las celdas que quieras en el botón en el que se haya hecho click.

En este código, basado en Javascript puro (puedes hacer algo parecido en jQuery pero te aconsejo que dependas lo menos posible de librerías externas), haremos lo siguiente:

Primero vamos a alcanzar todos los botones que estén en la tabla cuyo id es `table-id` usando `querySelectorAll()`.

Luego vamos a escuchar los clicks que ocurran en todos esos botones mediante eventos. Esto sustituye tu función in-line (no necesitas asignarla en el `while`). Aquí he metido toda la lógica dentro de la misma asignación del listener, pero puedes asignar una función aparte... Realmente no es necesario.

Después usaremos `parentNode` para referirnos a todas las celdas de la fila del botón sobre el que se hizo click.

Y finalmente obtendremos el valor de aquellas celdas que nos interesan usando su índice (en este caso sólo interesan las tres primeras celdas)... Cabe decir que en este punto cualquier otro tipo de lectura es posible, según la necesidad. Aquí lo he hecho a mano por simplificad y porque son pocos valores, pero en una tabla con muchas celdas puedes aquí hacer una lectura basada en un bucle u otra función avanzada de Javascript, por ejemplo, si necesitaras crear un objeto a partir de los valores de las celdas o cosas así.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  /*
    Referencia sólo a los button dentro de table-id
  */
  const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#table-id td button');

  /*
    Escuchamos los clicks de cualquier button
  */

  allButtons.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
      /*
        Referencia a todas las celdas de la fila actual
      */
      let allCells = elem.parentNode.parentNode.cells;

      /*
        Obtienes los valores que te interesan
      */
      cellA = allCells[0].textContent;
      cellB = allCells[1].textContent;
      cellC = allCells[2].textContent;
      /*
        Usar valores donde los requieras
        Test ...
      */
      console.log(cellA, cellB, cellC);

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-class" id="table-id" name="servicios_tabla">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nombre del servicio</th>
      <th>Categoria del servicio</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Acción</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="nr">Servicio1</td>
      <td>Categoría1</td>
      <td>Estado1</td>
      <td><button class='btn btn-primary' name='modificar' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#GSCCModal'>Modificar</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="nr">Servicio2</td>
      <td>Categoría2</td>
      <td>Estado2</td>
      <td><button class='btn btn-primary' name='modificar' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#GSCCModal'>Modificar</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="nr">Servicio3</td>
      <td>Categoría3</td>
      <td>Estado3</td>
      <td><button class='btn btn-primary' name='modificar' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#GSCCModal'>Modificar</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### Post-Data

Ahora que el código funciona y habiendo leído que quieres pasar los datos de las celdas a un modal, dejo caer la duda de que quiza no necesites un modal. Hoy día puedes actualizar parte del mismo contendor de forma dinámica, ganado en UX (experiencia de usuario) y en recursos. Imagina que incorporas tu "modal" en la misma página y lo muestras o lo ocultas según quieras, que le das un fondo de otro color etc... pues eso, cuando leo *modal* pienso en Windows 3.0 (eran los años 90 y las ventanas que emergían eran lo máximo). Eso quedó atrás hace mucho tiempo... Hoy día usar modales es cas siempre una pésima experiencia de usuario.

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo modal con popup? 
Por otro lado... entre Inertia, Livewire, TailwindCSS y AlpineJS, ya perdí toda vergüenza de violar la separación de responsabilidades.

Comment: @ffflabs hablo de modal si este se usa del modo tradicional (una ventana emergente aparte). En cuanto a los frameworks que mencionas no los conozco y no sé si OP los usa o piensa usarlos. Sea como sea, la separación de responsabilidades es un principio de programación ampliamente recomendado. Pero cada uno es libre de programar como quiera.

Comment: Solo intentaba reirme de mi mismo. Esos "frameworks" son lo último que se lleva y todos han tenido mucha tracción (o al menos muchos twitteros influyentes los están usando) Diría que casi todos te permiten prototipar rápido y luego maldecir por el resto del proyecto